# Error when trying to connect to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, skype4com

I am trying to program this thing where I clear one usernames chat history on Skype, so I have to use SQL Server to access `main.db` in the Skype `AppData` folder. However, I am receiving an error @ `maindb.Open();`:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)"

Here's my code (TEXTBOX9 is the username of the participant):

```
if (warningcrash == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        skype.SendMessage(textBox9.Text, textBox10.Text);
    }

    string participant = textBox9.Text;
    database = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA") + @"\Roaming\" + @"\Skype\" + skype.CurrentUserHandle + @"\main.db";

    Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("skype");
    proc[0].Kill();

    SqlConnection maindb = new SqlConnection("data source=" + database);

    SqlDataAdapter ad;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlCommand cmd;

    maindb.Open(); //error occurs here

    cmd = maindb.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "delete from Messages Where dialog_partner = '" + participant + "'";
    ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ad.Fill(dt);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype database is on SQL Lite 3, hence you will need to use SQLite.NET.dll library.

[Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application)

Comment: **Thanks so much, FIXED MY PROBLEM***